# Draw arc piece per piece based on song duration formulae doesn't work

Tags: android, math

I'm having a figure where an arc is on top with a light opacity. I want to draw my arc time at a time based on a song.

My oval is like this:

```
private void drawTimeArc(int angle, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG,"DrawTimeArc " + angle + " " + position);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(200);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p.setAlpha(10);

    RectF rectF = new RectF(100, 100, 500, 500);

    mCanvas.drawArc(rectF, position, angle, false, p);

    drawingImageView.invalidate();
}
```

Angle is the angle I wist to add and position is the position from where to draw. Initial position is 270 because that is 90 degrees. Why 270 because the drawArc draws clockwise.

My calculation to draw every second a piece of this is:

```
           long duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(mPlayer.getDuration());
                drawTimeArc((int)(360/duration), position);
                position += 360/duration;
```

Here mPlayer is a MediaPlayer.

I thought the circle is 360 degrees so 360 / duration gives you the angle you wish to add every second. Position starts on 270 and added so it shifts.

The problem is, that my song is finished and my circle is a little bit over the half. So it only does some +- 183 degrees.

Can someone tweak my formula? Because it must work with every song. So 360 * 2 isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is that I assign it to an int. So that's why it gave me always 1.

This is how you solve it:

```
      double duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(mPlayer.getDuration());
            int angle = (int) Math.ceil(360/duration);
            drawTimeArc(angle, position);
            position += angle;
```

You need a double and then do a ceil.

Answer (score 2):

I made something similar but for a progress dialog (same principle)

```
  //Draw arc (progressbar)
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(18);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(arcColor));
    RectF rectF = new RectF(screenWidth/2-100, screenHeight/2-100, screenWidth/2+100, screenHeight/2+100);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, -90, arcDrawValue, false, paint);
```

Github project: [Github project link](https://github.com/ManolescuSebastian/Custom-Progress-Dialog-Android)

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: And how can I calculate arcDrawValue?

Comment: I made something dummy in this project         while(arcDrawValue<360){
                    arcDrawValue++;
                    progressValue = (arcDrawValue)/3.6;}

Comment: Give me the value you receive from mPlayer.getDuration(), so I can reproduce your condition :)